# Duplicate tags for a device

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Recently I came across a [question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/14610/18061) that uses the tags [lumia-635](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-635) and [nokia-lumia-635](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia-635). I believe these tags should be marked as synonyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now set up as a synonym, and merged (to be consistent with others) :)